# Example of hyperbolic 3-manifold and faithful representations of fundamental group

Tags: representation-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

I am looking for a hyperbolic 3-manifold which is compact, closed, oriented with first betti number $\geq 1$ for which we can explicitely compute a discrete and faithful representation of its fundamental group in $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Any idea ?

Comment: [Snappy](https://snappy.math.uic.edu/) can compute pretty much anything you want to know. But what do you mean by "explicit"? For instance, if I give you a polynomial equation of 5th order with integer coefficients, what would it mean for you to "explicitly solve" this equation?

Comment: Have an exact value will be great but if I have an approximation I can work with.

Comment: I just read that Snappy was able to compute holonomy, I didn't know. Thank you.